# Can compressed javascript be uncompressed

Tags: javascript, compression

Is it possible to uncompress (if that's the right term even) for code like below?

```
var vote=function(){var k={informModerator:-1,undoMod:0,acceptedByOwner:1,upMod:2,downMod:3,offensive:4,favorite:5,close:6,reopen:7,deletion:10,undeletion:11,spam:12};var f=imagePath+"vote-arrow-down.png";var c=imagePath+"vote-arrow-down-on.png";var x=imagePath+"vote-arrow-up.png";var w=imagePath+"vote-arrow-up-on.png";var A=imagePath+"vote-favorite-on.png";var o=imagePath+"vote-favorite-off.png";var l=function(){var C='<a href="/users/login?returnurl='+escape(document.location)+'">login or register</a>';$("div.vote").find("img").not(".vote-accepted").unbind("click").click(function(D){u($(D.target),"Please "+C+" to use voting.")});z().unbind("click").click(function(D){u($(D.target),"Please "+C+" to flag this post.")})};var B=function(C){if(!C){C="div.vote"}$(C).find("img.vote-
```

I did search stackoverflow for this question and found no results

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Copy / paste here: http://jsbeautifier.org/

That will only **reformat** the layout. You cannot restore variable/function names.

**Related on MetaSO**: [Can we get an un-obfuscated version of the vote object?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/can-we-get-an-un-obfuscated-version-of-the-vote-object)

Comment: 5 years later... https://github.com/zertosh/beautify-with-words will rename your variables with "long-ish" unique names. It makes unminifed code less painful to read, and helps with find-and-replace.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like Eclipse can auto-format it for you. Won't be able to get back any of the original variable names though.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is see the original variables used to describe the code, then no.  You can always take the time to run it through a formatter to make it easier to read visually but the variable and function names are lost forever.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, you should be able to uncompress it.

Note, however, that most compressors will rename variables.  At that point, the code is, IMO, no longer human readable.

```
var vote = function() {
    var k = {
        informModerator: -1,
        undoMod: 0,
        acceptedByOwner: 1,
        upMod: 2,
        downMod: 3,
        offensive: 4,
        favorite: 5,
        close: 6,
        reopen: 7,
        deletion: 10,
        undeletion: 11,
        spam: 12
    };
    var f = imagePath + "vote-arrow-down.png";
    var c = imagePath + "vote-arrow-down-on.png";
    var x = imagePath + "vote-arrow-up.png";
    var w = imagePath + "vote-arrow-up-on.png";
    var A = imagePath + "vote-favorite-on.png";
    var o = imagePath + "vote-favorite-off.png";
    var l = function() {
        var C = '<a href="/users/login?returnurl=' + escape(document.location) + '">login or register</a>';
        $("div.vote").find("img").not(".vote-accepted").unbind("click").click(function(D) {
            u($(D.target), "Please " + C + " to use voting.")
        });
        z().unbind("click").click(function(D) {
            u($(D.target), "Please " + C + " to flag this post.")
        })
    };
    var B = function(C) {
        if (!C) {
            C = "div.vote"
        }
        $(C).find("img.vote-")
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called "Pretty Print" at Source tab in Developer Tools of Google Chrome. Click on curly bracket icon and see the formatted code.

[image: Here is a screen shot]