# Convert javascript from minified to uncompressed?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can compressed javascript be uncompressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190875/can-compressed-javascript-be-uncompressed)

How can I convert my javascript from mifified to uncompressed? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can compressed javascript be uncompressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190875/can-compressed-javascript-be-uncompressed) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166884/how-can-i-get-source-from-a-minified-javascript-file)

Answer (score 24):

http://jsbeautifier.org/

This is probably your best chance at making sense of minified code.  Good luck brave one!

Comment: +over9000 for "Good luck brave one!" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get exact uncompressed file by beautifying minified as variable names will be changed